# How to find the address of a cell found by LOOKUP?

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following formula to get the last non-zero value in a column:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Formula = "= LOOKUP(2,1/(H:H>1),H:H)"
```

It works nicely. But I would like to get the address of that cell. I have tried several lines of code found here and there and most boil down to something like this:

```
`Dim rb as Range
rb ="LOOKUP(2,1/(H:H>1),H:H)"
MsgBox(rb.Address)
MsgBox(rb.Row)
MsgBox(rb.Column)`
```

It goes without saying that it does not work. How can one find the address of the cell that LOOKUP returns? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with VBA, and use your original concept, you can use your current `Formula`, and afterwards use `Find` function to look from the end to find the row.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAddressofLookup()

Dim FindRng As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Formula = "= LOOKUP(2,1/(H:H>1),H:H)"

Set FindRng = ActiveSheet.Columns("H").Find(what:=ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Value, Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

MsgBox FindRng.Address


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Shai Rado, this works nicely; great idea to search from the bottom of the column! So, I can select that cell with          '.Range(FindRng.Address).Select' but to refer to a cell 5 columns to the right I would need FindRng.Column and FindRng.Row but that seems not to work.

Comment: @JSP to refer to a cell 5 columns to the right use FndRnd. Offset(, 5)

Comment: @Gary's student,@Shai Rado I am puzzled. My code now, with your suggestions, works correctly in a short sheet but not in my actual (rather large) sheet. I get the message "Run-time error 1004 (and others)" when I call for the MsgBox. I suspect one thing: the values have many decimals, does it matter? I am not sure I can post pictures here but I will try. And rather than make up values I will paste the real values. In the meantime, any hint about the reason? Thank you.

Comment: @JSP it shouldn't matter, how many decimals do you have ? I will try to test and see if I'm getting your error. Adding screen-shots of your relevant section will help

Comment: Will be travelling for some days, back soon.

Comment: I have now a screen dump that I will try to post below (if I have permission). 

Code:

    `Sub FindFetch()

    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Formula = "= LOOKUP(2,1/(A10:A26>0),A10:A26)"
  
     ''Fetch the value in the corresponding column C:
  
     ' ???
  
    ActiveSheet.Range("C???").Copy
  
    Range("C3").Select
  
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
  
    End Sub`

Comment: Nope, I cannot paste screen dump here.
/Users/jsp007/Desktop/20171217 Find and Fetch.png

Comment: @JSP the best thing is if you can open a new post, add you screen-shots, and latest modified code - this way other users in the future can follow each answer to each post

Comment: I want to write a new clarification comment but the web site says that comments can only be edit within 5 minutes. Not my best day.

Comment: And so I did, it looks much nicer with a screen dump. Maybe I should remove this old post altogether – but I cannot do it.

Comment: @JSP  you should keep it as you asked an answer and got a few answers which were upvoted, so in the future other users might use the information in this post

Comment: OK, will not touch it. But readers should also look at my new more explicit post (with more or less the same name), as per your suggestion; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worksheet formula will give the **address** of the last value in column **H** that is **greater than** zero:

```
="H"&LOOKUP(2,1/(H:H>0),ROW(H:H))
```

[image]

In *VBA*:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox "H" & Evaluate("LOOKUP(2,1/(H:H>0),ROW(H:H))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student, this works in the MsgBox but I cannot use that result to Select that cell and copy a cell on the same row but 5 places to the right. I need to transform the result (text?) into a real address.